# matlab: truncate large text and append '...'

Tags: regex, matlab, regexp-replace

I have a large array of text (`text`, stored as `cell-array`), that I want to truncate in matlab, say for 5 characters. Truncating with `regexprep` is quite efficient, but now, I would love to append a `'...'` at the end of every truncated match (and *only* there).

(How) can this be achieved within MATLAB's `regexprep`?

```
>> text = {'123456780','1','12'}; %<- small representative sample
>> regexprep(text,'(^.{0,5})(.*)','$1') %capture first 5 characters or less in first group (and replace the text with first group captures)

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'12345'}    {'1'}    {'12'}
```

it *should* read:

```
ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'12345...'}    {'1'}    {'12'}
```

Comment: sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched but couldn't find

Comment: Explanation for marking the solution: Upvoted both answers, but chose the one that preserves most characters while still answering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the string `12345...` is in fact 8 characters long. You don't want to make the mistake of truncating `1234567` to `12345...`, as the truncated version is longer and therefore shouldn't be truncated in the first place.

A solution that takes this into account is:

```matlab
regexprep(text,'^(.{5}).{3}.+','$1...')
```

which will only truncate if there are more than 8 characters and, if so, will display the first 5 with the trailing ellipsis.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```matlab
regexprep(text,'^(.{5}).+','$1...')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jWAiZf/1).

The main point is that you need to only trigger the replacement if a string is linger than five chars (else, you do not even need to truncate the string).

Note that `regexprep` returns the input string as is if there was no regex match found, thus you do not need to worry about strings that are zero to five chars long.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.{5})` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): any five chars
- `.+` - any one or more chars, as many as possible.